# How to trigger a event

Tags: javascript

Before anyone judges, that happens a lot on this site, i am new so any support i appreciate.

I want to activate a event in chrome console. i have found a event that i want to start but i can not find any way to activate it.
[Image: the event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCBST.jpg)

i have tried multiple commands but i keep getting errors: [Image: the commands i have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXI9x.jpg)

thanks for any help

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input")[1].innerHTML="FINDME!!!";
////REFERANCE 1
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("icon btn-icon icon-send");
input[0].click();
```

Before the code executes after reference 1 i need it to trigger the keyboard input event listener that i mentioned before otherwise the rest of the code will not work

Comment: Please share full code

Comment: I have added it

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch an event using the constructor `KeyboardEvent`

Try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input')[1].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('input'));
```

You can verify this works by appending an event handler on the same element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('input')[1].oninput = function () {console.log( 'works!' )}
```

You must add the event handler before dispatching the event, however.

Comment: Can this be used to dispatch a old event as in the code it says "new keyboardEvent" but when i remove the "new" word it says: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'KeyboardEvent': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Comment: `new` is a keyword. It doesn't have anything to do with the time the event was dispatched at. Everytime you need to dispatch an event, you need to create an event object and send it. You can read about `new` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new